# SQL Server error 5: “5(Access is denied.) while trying to read a trace file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I would like to read content of a trace file and write it into a table in SQL Server. As I have read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188425.aspx), `fn_trace_gettable` do ths job. I have this code:

```
select 
    IDENTITY(int, 1, 1) AS RowNumber, *  
into 
    mytracetest
from 
    fn_trace_gettable('C:\Users\Babak\Desktop\ITSM_Trace\trace.trc', default)
```

But I am getting this error:

> Msg 19049, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   File 'C:\Users\Babak\Desktop\ITSM_Trace\trace.trc' either does not exist or there was an error opening the file. Error = '5(Access is denied.)'.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188425.aspx, "Requires ALTER TRACE permission on the server."  Do you have TRACE permissions on the server?

Comment: I dont know. How can I grant it?

Comment: You need to be sysadmin level to grant but `GRANT ALTER TRACE TO <serverPrincipal>;`

Comment: Is this for a *remote* SQL Server instance? Is that `trace.trc` on that **server's** file system in `c:\users\babak\desktop\ ....` ?? SQL Server can only read from its own drives - not from your local disks...

Comment: @marc_s thank you man you have soved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this for a remote SQL Server instance?

Is that `trace.trc` on that server's file system in `c:\users\babak\desktop\....`?

SQL Server can only read from its own drives - not from the local disks on your own computer ...